# how to fetch data from dynamically added textboxes from jsp code

Tags: javascript, jsp, dynamic, textbox, onclick

Urgent..Anyone please Assist
how to access data from the elements added via javascript dynamically using the jsp code.
i am adding empty records on .jsp page using javascript (by calling a below function on click event of button) as :-

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.value="";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);            //and so on for 5 columns too
```

Main problem is that i am not able to access these dynamically added textboxes values from my jsp code. (because they have been created dynamically by javascript)

Now,i want to save the value from these dynamically added textboxes(in form of table) from the .jsp page to database using jsp...(there can be several rows generated depending upon user input)
or else suggest me code to create them dynamically so that i can fetch data from added dynamic textboxes on jsp page.
And please ..i don't want to go for servlet concept...wants using jsp only..

thnks ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you provide unique id and name to the textboxes you are adding?

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.value="";
    element1.id="empName[0]";
    element1.name="empName[0]";

cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

Like

```
<input type="text" id="empName[0]" name="empName[0]" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="empName[1]" name="empName[1]" value=""/>
```

Then on server side you can,

```
request.getParameter("empName[0]");
request.getParameter("empName[1]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var textboxes = [];
 var inputs = cell1.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
     if(inputs[i].type == "text")
          textboxes.push(inputs[i]);
          // or get name value pairs if not disabled: 
          // if(!inputs[i].disabled)
          //     myNameValues.push({ name: inputs[i].name, value: inputs[i].value });
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys for your assistance...
thanks The 1 again..it's working.
even it resolved my doubts too.